# Lavaan single group cfa. Empty categories but no grouping chosen?

Tags: r, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

I am trying to do a single factor cfa with lavaan. It works for every other variable but lavaan seems to have an issue with this specific indicator of this latent variable called "PFC46":

`fit <- cfa(model, data=data, ordered=c("other observed variables omitted ","PFC46"))`

I then get this error:

```
Error in lav_samplestats_step1(Y = Data, wt = wt, ov.names = ov.names,  : 
  lavaan ERROR: some categories of variable `PFC46' are empty in group 1; frequencies are [7 15 72 820 0]
```

But when I check if there are any empty variables I get this result with table()

```
1   2   3   4   5 
 
17  8  15  75 838
```

Does anyone have an idea why its not working? To me it looks like it executes the code as if I added some grouping, which to my knowledge I have not.

Tried to remove any missing values. The column of PFC46 looks exactly like any other where I do not get an error and If i omit PFC46 completely from the analysis it works. Also changed it to a factor, double, integer its all the same. Also double and triple checked the order and the model.